# How to stop Visual Studio 2017 from graying me code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 (v15.8.3), when I write a class field with C# and then a property for that field, the editor grays me the variable and the quick actions menu suggests me to use auto properties. How can I disable this behaviour? I don't want VS to go suggesting me to change to autoproperties, and I don't want code to be grayed out. I looked in options / text editor / C#, but couldn't find anything, and the quick launch for "quick actions" didn't show anything.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, found it. Don't know why I didn't saw this the first time. It didn't show in the "Quick actions" menu either. So, for future reference, here's a screenshot:

[image]